# Оптимизировать запрос

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте. Есть таблица транзакций. Типы:

- Daily Earning - дневной заработок
- Hold - временная заморозка суммы
- UnHold - разморозка
- Chargeback - штраф
- Bonus - безвозмездный подарок
- PayOut - выплата

Для типов кроме `Daily Earning`, поле `id_daily_earning` - это ссылка на какой либо день.
Нужно посчитать баланс, то есть от суммы заработка отнять сумму `Hold`, прибавить сумму `UnHold` и т.д.

Проблема в том, что при количестве записей в 100к запрос выполняется 15-20 сек

Вот пример таблицы:

[image: Imgur]

Вот таблица: http://pastebin.com/hFaBMNEM
Вот запрос: http://pastebin.com/XVZHdytE
Можно вставить создание таблицы и запрос сюда: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65a283

П.С. Группировки могут быть по разным полям. Там есть account_id и пр. В зависимости от группировки нужно видеть картину по заработкам (по дням, аккаунтам и пр.)

--
**UPDATE:**
Не могу сам ответить на свой вопрос.
В общем самый приемлемый вариант оказался таким:

```
SELECT  
     t2.id,  
     t2.offer_id,    
     SUM(t2.sum_hold) AS sum_hold,  
     SUM(t2.sum_unhold) AS sum_unhold,  
     SUM(t2.sum_chargeback) AS sum_chargeback,  
     SUM(t2.sum_bonus) AS sum_bonus,  
     SUM(t2.earning) AS sum_earning  
     FROM     
     (  
       SELECT  
       `t`.`id`,  
       `t`.`offer_id`,  
       `t`.`amount`,  
       SUM(IF(OtherTransactions.type = 'Hold', OtherTransactions.amount, 0)) AS sum_hold,  
       SUM(IF(OtherTransactions.type = 'UnHold', OtherTransactions.amount, 0)) AS sum_unhold,  
       SUM(IF(OtherTransactions.type = 'Chargeback', OtherTransactions.amount, 0)) AS sum_chargeback,  
       SUM(IF(OtherTransactions.type = 'Bonus', OtherTransactions.amount, 0)) AS sum_bonus,  
       t.amount AS earning  
       FROM `payments_transactions` `t`  
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `payments_transactions` `OtherTransactions`  
         ON (`OtherTransactions`.`id_daily_earning` = `t`.`id`)  
         AND (OtherTransactions.type = 'Hold'  
         OR OtherTransactions.type = 'UnHold'  
         OR OtherTransactions.type = 'Chargeback'  
         OR OtherTransactions.type = 'Bonus')  
       WHERE (t.type = "Daily Earning")  
       GROUP BY t.id  
   )  
   t2  
   GROUP BY t2.offer_id  
   ORDER BY t2.id DESC  
   LIMIT 30
```

Сначала джойним холды и пр (при JOIN нормально работают индексы), считаем их сумму в группировке по t.id. Как заработок берем не сумму amount, а просто amount. Затем оборачиваем это все в еще один запрос, в котором уже группируем как хотим, снова считаем суммы уже в этой группировке и делаем LIMIT.
На 350к записей отрабатывает за ~0.7 сек. Вполне терпимо.